# Geometric program with posynomial > 1

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, geometric-programming

I have an optimization setup where I can represent all objectives/constraints as posynomials.

Unfortunately one constraint has the form $g(x) > k$ where $g$ is a posynomial:

$$
\operatorname{minimize}_{R,G,a,C_1,C_2} R + \frac{1}{G} \left( k_1 + \frac{C_1}{a C_2}(1+G R) \right) k_2 \\
\mathrm{subject\,\,to} \\
a \left(1 + \frac{C_1}{C_2}(1+ G R)\right) > k_2 \\
\vdots
$$

For a valid geometric program, the constraints must have the form $g < k$.

Is there any hope to transform this into a valid geometric program?

Comment: I'm afraid not.

Comment: @Ned tried to answer your question. He recommends solving it as a [Signomial Program](http://gpkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/signomialprogramming.html). This link takes you to the GPkit documentation, which provides a good overview. Note that it cannot promise a global solution.

Comment: Thanks - great to get an answer from the CVX author himself! I use CVX which does not seem to support Signomial programming. I'll maybe remove the constraint and check it in an outer loop. If you make an answer out of it I can mark it as solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not enough reputation to join the comment thread above, but there's a [matlab script](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/63067-generalized-geometric-programming) which implements Maranas and Floudas's 1997 algorithm to provide a (slowish) global optimum for an SP which you may find useful.